# Conditional Distribution Deconstructing a Random Variable

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, conditional-probability

If I have a R.V $$X|Y=y\sim N(y,9)  \text{ and  } Y\sim N(10,8)$$ then $(X|y)=y+3Z$ where $Z\sim N(0,1).$ Is it possible to write $X$ as $X=Y+3Z$ to find the marginal distribution of $X$ i.e can I construct a random variable $Z$ that is independent of $Y$. Then will $$X=Y+3Z$$ have the same conditional distribution of $X|Y$. If this is true can I just get the marginal of $X$ through this form. $$E[X]=E[Y]+E[3Z]$$
$$Var(X)=Var(Y)+Var(3Z)$$ 
Then $X\sim N(10,17)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The specific way your $X$ depends on $Y$ makes this work.  We have

$$\forall y: (X \mid Y=y) \sim N(y, 9) = y + N(0, 9)$$

so $X = Y + N(0, 9)$, where the $N(0, 9)$ is independent of $Y$.  Your results then follow.

Note that if the dependence were different, e.g. $(X \mid Y=y) \sim Uniform(0, |y|)$ then this kind of "decomposition" may not work.

Comment: Theoretically, how would  I construct the independent $N(0,9)$ to my Y

Comment: Well if we get into measure theory and sigma algebras, I'm out of my depth.  But if you take the view that a certain probability space was given to you, and in that space there lived $X, Y$, and they are jointly distributed as you said, then $W := X-Y$ is already $\sim N(0,9)$ and independent of $Y$.